# ピクセルの画素値情報を取得する方法

Tags: spresense, arduino

spresense main board とcamera boardを利用して arduino ideで画素値を取得しようと考えています。
getImgBuff()を使用して画素値を得ることは可能でしょうか。
またspresenseを使い始めたばかりでgetImgBuff()が何を得ることができるのがあまり分かっておらず、`uint16_t *buff =  (uint16_t*)img.getImgBuff();`として得た値が画像の左上の画素値を取得できるという認識なのですが、この認識であっているでしょうか。以下のコードで画像左上の画素値を出力しましたが、`Serial.println(*buff, BIN);`で出できた値が自分では16ビットで出てくると思っていたのですが実際はそれよりも少ないビット数で出てきてしまいました。何かコードが変であったり、認識が違う箇所がありましたら教えていただきたいです。コードのほとんどはカメラサンプルコードを利用しています。

```
#include <Camera.h>
#include <stdio.h>  /* for sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>

#define BAUDRATE (115200)
int take_picture_count = 0;
void printError(enum CamErr err)
{
  Serial.print("Error: ");
  switch (err)
    {
      case CAM_ERR_NO_DEVICE:
        Serial.println("No Device");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_ILLEGAL_DEVERR:
        Serial.println("Illegal device error");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_ALREADY_INITIALIZED:
        Serial.println("Already initialized");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        Serial.println("Not initialized");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_NOT_STILL_INITIALIZED:
        Serial.println("Still picture not initialized");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_CANT_CREATE_THREAD:
        Serial.println("Failed to create thread");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_INVALID_PARAM:
        Serial.println("Invalid parameter");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_NO_MEMORY:
        Serial.println("No memory");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_USR_INUSED:
        Serial.println("Buffer already in use");
        break;
      case CAM_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED:
        Serial.println("Operation not permitted");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}

void CamCB(CamImage img)
{

  /* Check the img instance is available or not. */

  if (img.isAvailable())
    {

      /* If you want RGB565 data, convert image data format to RGB565 */
      img.convertPixFormat(CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_RGB565);

      /* You can use image data directly by using getImgSize() and getImgBuff().
       * for displaying image to a display, etc. */
      Serial.print("Image data size = ");
      Serial.print(img.getImgSize(), DEC);
      Serial.print(" , ");
      int width = img.getWidth();
      int height = img.getHeight();
      Serial.println("widthsize");
      Serial.println(width);
      Serial.println("heightsize");
      Serial.println(height);
      Serial.println("buff addr = ");
      uint16_t *buff =  (uint16_t*)img.getImgBuff();
      Serial.println(*buff, BIN);
      unsigned short r = *buff >> 11;
      int red = r*8 ;
      unsigned short g = (*buff >> 5) & 0b111111;
      int green = g*4;
      unsigned short b = *buff & 0b11111;
      int blue = b*8;
      Serial.println("r");
      Serial.println(red);
      Serial.println("g");
      Serial.println(green);
      Serial.println("b");
      Serial.println(blue);
      
    }
  else
    {
      Serial.print("Failed to get video stream image\n");
    }
}

void setup()
{
  CamErr err;
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  while (!Serial)
  {
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Prepare camera");
  theCamera.begin();
  Serial.println("Start streaming");
  err = theCamera.startStreaming(true, CamCB);
  Serial.println("Set Auto white balance parameter");
  err = theCamera.setAutoWhiteBalanceMode(CAM_WHITE_BALANCE_DAYLIGHT);
  Serial.println("Set still picture format");
  err = theCamera.setStillPictureImageFormat(
     CAM_IMGSIZE_QUADVGA_H,
     CAM_IMGSIZE_QUADVGA_V,
     CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPG);
}

void loop()
{
  
  if (take_picture_count < 3)
    {
    // カメラから静止画を取得
    Serial.println("Taking picture...");
    CamImage img = theCamera.takePicture();
    if (img.isAvailable())
      {  

      }
     take_picture_count++;
    
    }
  else
  {
    theCamera.end();
  }
  delay(1000); // 1秒待機して次の画像を取得
}
```

Comment: 持っていないので詳しくないけど, `setStillPictureImageFormat`で JPEG指定してるので RGBの値取り出すには JPEG展開が必要では？RGB565 の指定であれば 16bitの画素値取り出せるカモ

Comment: @oriri
返信ありがとうございます。実際にsetStillPictureImageFormatのCAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPGをRGB565に変更して実行してみましたが16ビットで出力されませんでした。該当箇所のみの変換ではダメだということでしょうか？

Comment: ① `setup()` 呼び出して JPEGにセットし, そのまま画像取得し, サイズ分書き出してみる。② 今度は RGB565でセットし, 同様に取得し書き出してみる。①,②でサイズも内容も異なるはずです。JPEGで書き出したものは他から JPEG形式と認識されるはず

Comment: RGB565にしたものとJPEGにしたものでのフォーマットの違いをgetPixFormat()で確認しました。結果は確かにtheCamera.takePicture()で画像を取得した直後にはフォーマットの変化が見られましたが、void CamCB内は変わらずでした。自分としてはvoid CamCB内のimg.convertPixFormatでRGB565に変換しているためそこでRGBには変換しており、uint16_t *buff =  (uint16_t*)img.getImgBuff();として得た値もRGB565フォーマットで取得出来ていると思うのですがどうでしょうか？

Comment: (個人的には)JPEG指定することなく, 最初からずっと RGB565 で行えばよいのでは？と思いますが (convertPixFormat() 呼び出さずに)。どこかのタイミングで RGB565ではない形式になってるので失敗してるのでは？

Comment: JPEGからRGB565に変換するのは余計だったため、最初からRGB565にして行いましたが今までと同じ結果でした。また現象として画像の違いによりビット数が変化するといったことも起きています。たとえば画像を取得するためのカメラを手で覆い、その状態で得た画像の値をRGB565で出力すると16bitで出力していました。ただし通常は15bitで出力されています。こういったことは起こりえるのでしょうか？

Comment: 現在もソースが質問時の構造のままなら, `startStreaming()`をいきなり開始するのではなく, 先に `set*` で設定行うのはどうでしょう (`setAutoWhiteBalanceMode`, `setStillPictureImageFormat`) (元のソースはフォーマットを色々変更しながら動かしてるのでは？)
(逆に, RGB565に初期化しててそれ以外が取得されるのは変だと思うので)

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません．ご指摘された内容も考慮しながら色々試してみましたが上手くいきませんでした．またgetImgBuffを使うと，自分が最終的にしたいことに対して別の障害も出てきたため今は一旦libjpegを使用して進めることにしました．今まで様々な解決策を提示して下さりありがとうございます．また，上手くいきましたらコメントに残そうと思います．